# Is UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum slow in iOS SDK 4.0?

Tags: iphone, ios4

I use UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum to save picture to album. But after updated to iOS SDK 4.0, I noticed that it was slowed down significantly. It's about 20 seconds, between UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum was issued and completionSelector was triggered.
Can anyone help on this problem?

Comment: You can use ALAssetLibrary as an alternative

Comment: We want to keep the compatibility to early versions of iOS, and ALAssetLibrary is available in 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum is not stable. Sometimes it works, sometimes not.